# Instantiating a unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of strings called magazine,and i want to insert all of the strings from the vector to a unordered_multiset. I wrote a code like this.

```
unordered_multiset<string> magazine_set;

for (auto i = magazine.begin(); i != magazine.end(); i++){
    magazine_set.insert(*i);
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this.?

Comment: RTFM. There's lots of documentation available for `std::multiset`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the constructor:

```
unordered_multiset<string> magazine_set(magazine.begin(), magazine.end());
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of the `insert` member function function that takes two iterators.

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

You can use:

```
unordered_multiset<string> magazine_set;
magazine_set.insert(magazine.begin(), magazine.end());
```